# How to plot a 3d graph in JavaScript with non square data

Tags: javascript, graph

I'm trying to plot a 3d graph, but every example or tutorial I find use square data (x and y are the same length), like this one: https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-surface-plots/

My sample data is an csv file with three columns, so something like this:

```
2020-04-04 9:01:02,14034,402
2020-04-04 9:01:03,14031,410
2020-04-04 9:01:04,14031,431
2020-04-04 9:01:05,14032,435
2020-04-04 9:01:06,14033,432
2020-04-04 9:01:07,14030,432
2020-04-04 9:01:08,14032,427
2020-04-04 9:01:09,14030,423
2020-04-04 9:01:10,14029,420
2020-04-04 9:01:11,14030,418
2020-04-04 9:01:12,14029,425
2020-04-04 9:01:13,14030,426
2020-04-04 9:01:15,14031,420
2020-04-04 9:01:16,14028,421
2020-04-04 9:01:17,14029,423
2020-04-04 9:01:18,14032,434
2020-04-04 9:01:19,14034,435
2020-04-04 9:01:20,14034,435
2020-04-04 9:01:21,14033,430
2020-04-04 9:01:22,14033,426
2020-04-04 9:01:23,14034,426
```

Repeated for 4000 rows.

I tried to use it in the code example but it doesn't work, should I manipulate the data in a particular way? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect your data to translate to a 3d graph? The data from Mt. Bruno from the plotly examples is a [2d array](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv) where the cells contain the height of the elevation. (I assume this is what you mean by 'square data').

Your data includes timestamps, each with one point in a cartesian space. It kind of resembles the position of one object over time.

One way of visualising such data can be a [heat map](https://plotly.com/javascript/heatmaps/), where multiple 'hits' for an area change the color. In order to use the plotly heat map feature you would have to create a grid structure with arrays and then count how many data points fall into each grid cell.